# Can I add an options menu to my VSIX extension without adding a VSPackage?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, vsix, vspackage, visual-studio-sdk

I have a very lightweight Visual Studio extension. It's currently just a MouseProcessor and a KeyboardProcessor in one class file, a vsixmanifest, and the necessary two icons.

I want to add a simple menu for it in the Tools > Options. Just a boolean to toggle on/off.

It's my first extension, and it was quite a learning curve to get this far. Every tutorial I find assumes that I'm using a VSPackage, and in fact, MSDN doesn't make it clear that you can have an extension without one. Obviously this isn't the case, though.

Using a VSPackage, or at least, creating a new VSPackage project, seems like it adds a whole lot of weight to the project. I'm wondering if there's a very light way to add a simple Options menu to my extension, either without a VSPackage or with a very small VSPackage load.

The code in question is on GitHub at https://github.com/norachuga/MiddleClickToPeekDefinition . It lets you middle-click on a word to Peek Definition, or ctrl+middleclick to Go To Definition. I want to add a boolean menu option to flip those, so middle-click is Go To Definition and ctrl+middleclick is Peek Definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lightest possible VSPackage is demonstrated in commit [f3e23a3 here](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/vsbase/commit/f3e23a343eade6137e4f559d3764f83832e61bb9). In particular, you need the following:

1. A class derived from `Package`, similar to [`OutputWindowPackage`](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/vsbase/blob/f3e23a343eade6137e4f559d3764f83832e61bb9/OutputWindow/OutputWindowPackage.cs). Keep the `PackageRegistration` attribute, but you can omit `ProvideBindingPath` if your extension only has one assembly. You can simplify the dependencies by referencing the [`VSSDK.Shell.12`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/VSSDK.Shell.12/) NuGet package (for an extension only targeting Visual Studio 2013 and newer).
2. Update the `source.extension.vsixmanifest` to include the `<VsPackage>|%CurrentProject%|</VsPackage>` line.
3. Update the project file to set `<GeneratePkgDefFile>true</GeneratePkgDefFile>` and `<CopyBuildOutputToOutputDirectory>true</CopyBuildOutputToOutputDirectory>`.
4. Make sure the project file has `<IncludeAssemblyInVSIXContainer>true</IncludeAssemblyInVSIXContainer>` (it should even before you update the project).

Comment: This worked with one small change. I had to skip step 3, and in the Project properties, I had to check "Copy VSIX content to the following location" and set it to the bin\Debug folder. I then had to build the application once (to get it to copy it). After this, I could then set GeneratePkgDefFile to true and build without error.